# Properly formatting an execute alter with variable and table name in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to execute on an alter table to assign a column to a sequence `nextval` for an auto-increment, but can't seem to figure out how to do this last part. The sequence is created fine, owners are all asigned, and `table_a.id` is the owner of `table_a_id_seq`. I've already created `table_a_id_seq`.

In a postgres sql function, how do I format this correctly.

I've tried:

```
EXECUTE format('ALTER TABLE ONLY %s ALTER COLUMN id SET DEFAULT nextval($1::regclass)', new_table_name) USING new_seq_name;
```

But it says that $1 is not pointing to `new_table_seq_name`.
I've also tried:

```
EXECUTE format('ALTER TABLE ONLY %s ALTER COLUMN id SET DEFAULT nextval("%s"::regclass)', new_table_name, new_seq_name);
```

But it tells me the sequence doesn't exist which makes me wonder if it needs to be behind a transaction separated by this statement.

How can I successfully execute this alter on `new_table_name`? Thanks for the help!

Comment: `select sequence_schema,sequence_name from information_schema.sequences where sequence_schema ='yourschema' and sequence_name = 'new_seq_name';` would you please just make sure you define schema and seq name well?..

Comment: Do you want to achieve sth like in **[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/a1e04/1/2)**?

Comment: just to be sure you use `nextval('"myschema".foo')` syntax (unless you have schema in search path)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [the format specifier `%L`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-string.html) for a literal:

```
EXECUTE format(
    'ALTER TABLE ONLY %s ALTER COLUMN id SET DEFAULT nextval(%L::regclass)', 
    new_table_name, 
    new_seq_name);
```